# If the vectors <x> and <y> are not parallel why must the coefficients match for the equation a<x> + b<y> = c<x> + d<y>?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

That is a = c and b = d.  Note: I am self studying multivariable calculus using u tube and Shifrin's lectures. I am OK with lecture #2 , I understood all the examples accept he gave this to the people in the room to take home and they have the benefit to see him do it in class.  I don't have that luxury and am not so smart to see the answer.  By the way ....I shouldn't say this but if anyone has a better lecture series for multivariable calculus and wants to share it with me I won't object although it is a second question and maybe not permitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you re-arrange, you get $(a-c)<x> = (d-b)<y>,$ so that $$<x>= \frac{d-b}{a-c}<y>,$$ assuming $a \neq c$, which make $<x>$ and $<y>$ parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it as
$(a-c)<x>
=(d-b)<y>
$.

If $a \ne c$
or
$b \ne d$,
then $<x>$ and $<y>$
are scalar multiples of each other,
and so must be parallel.